# APACHE SOLR: Pass a file as query parameter and then parse each line to form a criteria

Tags: solr, lucene

PROBLEM: I have a huge file of 10000 lines i want this to be an inclusion or exclusion in the query . i.e each line like ( line1 or line2 or ..)

How can this be achieved in solr , is there a custom implementation that i would need to implement.
Also will it help to implement a custom filter ?

Comment: So you want to enrich a search with at least 10.000 terms? Meaning `Term`== one phrase of a line of your file. Why do you want to do that? Probably there is a better way ...

Comment: Yes what i want is something like : field: ("stringA" OR "stringB" ... OR "string N") where N can be a huge number . I get these strings from the file. Would be glad if u could suggest a way. Thank You.

Comment: Yes, but *why?*  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Are you, by chance, trying to [find similar documents](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis)?